# Send a Message from Client (Android-Mobile) to Server (Python)

Tags: java, android, python-3.x, sockets, socket.io

I am working on a project that has a server (Python 3.x) and a client (Android Studio). The client (mobile phone) takes an image (bitmap) and sends it to the server (Python). In the server part, it does some Deep Learning stuff and generates a prediction. So, I need to send that prediction (string) to the client back. However, I am using a socket programming and it does not work. I have been worked on it for a long time, and the deadline is coming. So, could someone please help me?

The error MAY BE cause of clientSocket.getInputStream() (But I am not sure)

HERE İS HOW SERVER (PYTHON) LOOKS LİKE

```
import socket
import base64

HOST = 'localhost'  
PORT = 5433        # 1023 ten büyük bir sayı olsun.

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen(5)
    i = 1 #Dosya adıyla ilgili.

    while True:
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        with conn:
            print(' > connected by ', addr)

            #Take image that was sent from Client
            data = base64.b64encode(b'')
            while True:     
                yenidata = conn.recv(1024)            
                if not yenidata:
                    break            
                data = data + yenidata 

            #Save the image to do DL part.
            fileName = 'yeniResim'+str(i)
            with open("C:/Users/MUSTAFAAKTAS/Desktop/Indirilenler/"+fileName+".png", "wb") as fh:
                fh.write((base64.decodebytes(data))) 
                i = i + 1 
                print(" >",fileName," saved.")

            #In here, I randomly wrote "Message", but in real, I do some DL stuff and try to send the prediction to the Client
            conn.send(bytes("Message",'UTF-8'))
            print(" > Message sent")
```

NOW CLİENT (ANDROİD) PART HERE,

```
#I create a connection like this,
Socket client = new Socket(IP, PORT);

#I need 'cevap' which is the prediction that was sent from the server to client
String cevap = ServerRespond();


public String ServerRespond(){

        if(client.isClosed()) {
            return "SERVER Closed";
        }
        else {
                try {
                    ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(5433);
                    Socket s = ss.accept();
                    InputStream sin = s.getInputStream();
                    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(sin);
                    return dis.readUTF().toString();
                } catch (SocketTimeoutException s) {
                    return "Socket timed out!";
                } catch (Exception ioe) {
                    return "IO HATASI " + ioe.getLocalizedMessage();
                }

        }
    }
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: What exactly is not working in your script??? Do you establish a stream between the server and the client? if not what part of the script is not working?

Comment: In android part I did like, Socket client = new Socket(IP, PORT);
and server part, with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))

How can I send an image to server and immediately after, send a prediction to the client?